# R tuple as factor (specifically longitude lattitude as factor)

Tags: r, indexing, tuples

I am having problems with accessing factors in `R`. I have a dataframe of tuple factor

```
test1
#[1] (34.0467, -118.2470) (34.0637, -118.2440) (34.0438, -118.2547)
#[4] (34.0523, -118.2676) (34.0584, -118.2810) (34.0583, -118.2616)
#39497 Levels: (0, 0) (0.0000, 0.0000) ... (34.6837, -118.1853)
```

How do I access just the first digit of the tuple?

thanks!

> dput(test1)
>   ...
>   "(34.3256, -118.4307)", "(34.3256, -118.4798)", "(34.3256, -118.5033)", 
>   "(34.3257, -118.4244)", "(34.3258, -118.4343)", "(34.3262, -118.4104)", 
>   "(34.3262, -118.4112)", "(34.3266, -118.4234)", "(34.3266, -118.4269)", 
>   "(34.3266, -118.4323)", "(34.3269, -118.4278)", "(34.3272, -118.4365)", 
>   "(34.3273, -118.4342)", "(34.3274, -118.4321)", "(34.3274, -118.4331)", 
>   "(34.3275, -118.4247)", "(34.3275, -118.4298)", "(34.3276, -118.4115)", 
>   "(34.3277, -118.4071)", "(34.3285, -118.4266)", "(34.3286, -118.4277)", 
>   "(34.3287, -118.4286)", "(34.3292, -118.5048)", "(34.3293, -118.4246)", 
>   "(34.3298, -118.4300)", "(34.3327, -118.5062)", "(34.3374, -118.5042)", 
>   "(34.3760, -118.5254)", "(34.3767, -118.5263)", "(34.3775, -118.5270)", 
>   "(34.3805, -118.5293)", "(34.4638, -118.1995)", "(34.5095, -117.9273)", 
>   "(34.5304, -118.1418)", "(34.5453, -118.0405)", "(34.5650, -118.0856)", 
>   "(34.5693, -118.0228)", "(34.5957, -118.1784)", "(34.6818, -118.0954)", 
>   "(34.6837, -118.1853)"), class = "factor")

Can't get the beginning of that anyhow.

Comment: How exactly is `x=((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))` stored in R? Provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) (perhaps use `dput()`). Data.frames don't like to store non-atomic vectors as columns.

Comment: So you have literal strings that are coded as factors? What you shared is not a `dput` so it's not super helpful. Also you should edit your question to include that information so it can be properly formatted (rather than including as a comment).

Comment: dput is very large. basically it's longitudinal/lattitude csv file read.csv into a data frame.

Comment: dput(head(test))
"(34.5693, -118.0228)", "(34.5957, -118.1784)", "(34.6818, -118.0954)", 
"(34.6837, -118.1853)"), class = "factor")

Comment: I suppose you have read the data from a file, right? What was the exact command you used to do that?

Comment: read.csv() is what i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test1 <- factor(c("(34.3242, -118.4494)", "(34.3242, -118.4914)", "(34.3243, -118.4167)"))
```

First, convert the factor vector to a character vector.

```
test1 <- as.character(test1)
```

Then, remove all `(`s and `)`s, and split the strings by `,`.

```
test1 <- gsub("\\(|\\)", "", test1)
test1 <- strsplit(test1, ",")
```

After that, change the digits from character format to numeric format.

```
test1 <- lapply(test1, as.numeric)
```

Finally, get the first coordinate of each point (change `1` to `2`, if you want the second one).

```
test1 <- unlist(lapply(test1, '[[', 1))
```

Here is the output.

```
> test1
[1] 34.3242 34.3242 34.3243
```

Answer (score 0):

Just index again

```
x[1][1]
x[2][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",as.character(test1)),","))[c(T,F)])
```

**Explanation**

`gsub` is applicable only on `character`. So, `as.character(test1)` is converting `test1` to `character` from `factor`. Then I am removing `"(" & ")"` from them like this

```
gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",as.character(test1))
#[1] "34.5693, -118.0228" "34.5957, -118.1784" "34.6818, -118.0954" "34.6837, -118.1853"
```

Later I split them into two parts depending on the separator `,` as

```
strsplit(gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",as.character(test1)),",")
#[[1]]
#[1] "34.5693"    " -118.0228"

#[[2]]
#[1] "34.5957"    " -118.1784"

#[[3]]
#[1] "34.6818"    " -118.0954"

#[[4]]
#[1] "34.6837"    " -118.1853"
```

Previous output is a list. `unlist` made output a vector.

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("[\\(\\)]", "",as.character(test1)),","))
#[1] "34.5693"    " -118.0228" "34.5957"    " -118.1784" "34.6818"    " -118.0954"
#[7] "34.6837"    " -118.1853"
```

Basically `[c(T,F)]` is generating an alternating sequence of `TRUE` and `FALSE` for selection of first elements.

At last I made the output `numeric` using `as.numeric`

**Output**

```
#[1] 34.5693 34.5957 34.6818 34.6837
```

Comment: gives...[1] 34.0467 34.0637 34.0438 34.0523 34.0584 34.0583 ... but what is [c(T,F)]? anyhow i think this isn't possible and i just break the tuples into a matrix instead. i think python has ways to work with tuple or maybe i'm not understanding factors here.

Comment: good point. that is the result i wanted i just don't get what you did. thanks.

Comment: @bottledatthesource : See explanation